# Is there some guides for designing error code in C

Tags: c, return-value, error-code

It has confused me for a long time that is there a good way to design error code in C as the return code. I used to use magic number or global macro to define a specific error like using -1 as general failure. But when the project becomes large, I find it not easy to manage these error code. Can someone give me an example or a guide for how to design good error codes?

I used to consider that the error code may be split into some bit fields to specify the type of error or the function which throws the error or something else. I'm finding inspiration and there isn't a specific project for the error code. Maybe there are some good coded error codes in some famous projects that you know, please tell me the name of that project

I'll appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use [`enum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages) data types. for example:

```
typedef enum { KEY_NOT_FOUND, INVALID_DATA } errortype;
```

Comment: You are right. I think my question may changed to "How to code an error code". For example: use first 8bit of an int variable as the type of error and other bits indicates the specific error.

Answer (score 2):

[strerror](http://ieee.uwaterloo.ca/coldfire/gcc-doc/docs/libc_99.html) provide user defined error codes.This implementation of `strerror` provides for user-defined extensibility. `errno.h` defines `__ELASTERROR`, which can be used as a base for user-defined error values.

Comment: It helps me. It provides some common error and I can extend it myself. So the future question is how to code the user-defined error code. I think a simple integer is good for many project, but there should be some way of coding to make the error code easier to be managed.

Comment: @Arthur please elaborate how exactly you want to code your error code(i mean some layout). You can reedit your post to make it more clear(there you can get lot of space too to write.).You already have a simple and perfect solution in form of grijesh's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have no exact idea about the error code. I am just finding inspiration.